# Azure Api management - call non-Azure API?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

When it comes to Azure services (App service, Azure functions etc.) then it´s straightforward to connect these to the API-management, but can´t find a way when it comes to  my external (non-Azure APIs).

Is it possible from the Azure Management API to also call my external APIs - which are not located within Azure?

Comment: Hope this document is what you are looking for. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#SendOneWayRequest

Comment: According to my understanding, you can access  API  APIs hosted on-premises and across clouds for Azure API management. If so, you can use Self-hosted API Management gateway in API managemeant. It  expands API Management support for hybrid and multi-cloud environments and enables organizations to efficiently and securely manage APIs hosted on-premises and across clouds from a single API Management service in Azure. For more details, please refer to http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/self-hosted-gateway-overview

Comment: Thanks @Jim Xu, but Self-hosted gateway seems to not be released yet.

Comment: According to the official document I provide, it is in preview. So we just can use it Developer and Premium tiers with no additional charge.

Comment: I can´t find it from API management or the Azure portal.

Comment: Regrading how to use it, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-provision-self-hosted-gateway

Comment: @Kran Is it useful for you? Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

are you using external or internal. external should just work so long as the dns is public. for internal you need to check the vnet and nsg rules. check if you have 0.0.0.0 (any address) allowed. if possible integrating App Insights help identify connectivity issues.